# How to eneable the media keys?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, media-buttons

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, and I'm using DasKeyboard Pro 4. The Sleep and Mute keys are working fine, the Volume knob also works fine. the Play/Pause, Next and Precious Track buttons are not working at all. I tried manually assigning them from the keyboard settings options. Please help!

EDIT: xev results -

• Previous Track

```
KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x5a00001,
    root 0x14f, subw 0x0, time 18634421, (171,-12), root:(274,81),
    state 0x10, keycode 173 (keysym 0x1008ff16, XF86AudioPrev), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

• Next Track

```
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x5a00001,
    root 0x14f, subw 0x0, time 18983219, (623,348), root:(726,441),
    state 0x10, keycode 171 (keysym 0x1008ff17, XF86AudioNext), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

• Play/Pause

```
FocusOut event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x4e00001,
    mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x4e00001,
    mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

EDIT2:

There seems to be a general problem with the keyboard shortcuts. For example, when reassigning ctrl + print to capture window to clipboard, it not working (the default ctrl + alt + print do work). Creating a custom shortcuts for example for flameshot gui do work, but creating a custom shortcut for the media keys do not resolve my problem. I'm getting perplexed here, any Ideas? I'm new to linux (2 days) and I'm actually starting to fall in love with it, but it kinda strange that certain things that should be really smooth and simple are requiring hours to figure out.

Comment: start `xev` in commandline and press the buttons. Please post the results for a sequence for 1 keycode press into the question. If xev does not respond you need a driver...

Comment: @Rinzwind done.

Comment: removed my answer; it is an outdated method. where I said `xev` use `sudo showkey -s` instead and `xmodmap -pke | less` to view the current keycodses with the event. It looks like "0x11" where 11 is what you need. If you need  one find an empty line and use ` setkeycodes {yourscancode} {emptyone-8}`  (ie subtract 8 from the number to use).